# jConfirm with this existing code

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, alerts, confirm

I need help to use jConfirm with this existing code (php & Jquery & jAlert).

```
function logout()
{
  if (confirm("Do you really want to logout?"))
    window.location.href = "logout.php";

}
```

If I just change confirm to jConfirm this not enough to make it work...

Thanks for your help

Lena

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function logout()
{
  jConfirm('Do you really want to logout?', 'Logout', function(r) {
    if (r)
       window.location.href = "logout.php";
  });
}
```

**EDIT for comments:**

```
function sid(id){
  $_sidId = id;
  jConfirm("Delete System ID for " + id + "?", 'Delete Sid', function(r) {
    if (r){
       window.location.href = "del_sid.php?id=" + $_sidId;
    }
    $_sidId = null;
  });
}
```

When I saw the script better, it would be desirable to remove the variable "$_sidId" from "if", no matter the response, it would have to clean up the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working perfectly!

I have tried to do the same for this other confirmation without success...
Could you help me with this one too?

function sid(id)
{
  if (confirm("Delete System ID for " + id + "?"))
    window.location.href = "del_sid.php?id=" + id;
}